# RoR 4 & TurboLinks 5 cache issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, cart, turbolinks

I have a classic cart application made in RoR 4 using turbolinks5. The user is able to change the quantity of a given item and click the "Update cart" button to update the cart values.

The "Update cart" button submits an Ajax form (data-remote="true") in order to update the cart and increments/decrements a cart item counter placed in the menu.

Now the problem is: every time the user clicks the "Update cart" button a new page of the cart is cached, so if the user updated the cart 3 times and then clicks browser's "back button" it will display three old versions of the cart (stored in cache).

So:

1. I have used `<meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-cache">` for the cart page and this fixes the problem but it seems like an overkill.
2. I have used `data-turbolinks-permanent` on the element that contains the cart item count(`<li class="active" id="cart_total_items" data-turbolinks-permanent>222<\li>`) and it does not works, this is, when "back button" is clicked the old count is shown instead the new one.
3. if i use `<meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-cache">` for all pages it works, but obviously i want to used page caching

So any idea why this is not working?

Warm Regards

Comment: Try to write code in this event
 $(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
    // your code
 });

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the for the [Canceling visits before they start](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#canceling-visits-before-they-start)

> Application visits can be canceled before they start, regardless of whether they were initiated by a link click or a call to Turbolinks.visit.
>
> Listen for the turbolinks:before-visit event to be notified when a visit is about to start, and use event.data.url (or $event.originalEvent.data.url, when using jQuery) to check the visit’s location. Then cancel the visit by calling event.preventDefault().
>
> Restoration visits cannot be canceled and do not fire turbolinks:before-visit. Turbolinks issues restoration visits in response to history navigation that has already taken place, typically via the browser’s Back or Forward buttons.

By listening for the `visit` event to be fired and intercepting it, you can prevent turbolinks from caching the page.